# pwntools: Setting context.terminal in command line tools

Tags: security, pwntools

In pwntools, how can I set the `context.terminal` for command line tools, such as `pwn debug`.  Using `-c` fails with error.

Answer (score 0):

pwntools auto-configure to open the terminal you're using to enter the command.

This option (`-c / --configure`) is used to set the os/architecture/endianness/bits the shellcode will run in.